# Values are changed when inserted in Bundle

Tags: android, android-activity, parcelable

When I put an object into a bundle so I can transfer it to another Activity, changing the value of the attribute IdEscritorio occurs. 
In my LoginActivity IdEscritorio the value of = 1, when I get in my Main Activity is it with the value of 7.

**LogCat**
[image]

**LoginActivity Method**

```
private void IniciarMainActivity(Usuario usuarioAutenticado)
{
    //Iniciar Activity Main
    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putParcelable("usuarioAutenticado", usuarioAutenticado);

    Log.d(TAG, "IdEscritorio: " +  String.valueOf(usuarioAutenticado.getIdEscritorio()));

    i.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

**MainActivity onCreate()**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Widgets
    InicializeComponents();

    //Listeners Events
    Listeners();

    //Recuperar os valores de usuario autenticado enviado da activity Login
    _usuarioAutenticado = new Usuario();
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();        
    if(bundle != null)
        _usuarioAutenticado = bundle.getParcelable("usuarioAutenticado");

    Log.d(TAG, "IdEscritorio: " +  String.valueOf(_usuarioAutenticado.getIdEscritorio()));
}
```

**Class Usuario**

```
public class Usuario implements Parcelable {

    private int Id;
    private int IdEscritorio;
    private String Nome;
    private String Login;
    private String Senha;   

    /**
     * Construtores
     */
    public Usuario()
    {
        super();
    }

    public Usuario(Parcel parcel)
    {
        this();
        this.Id = parcel.readInt();
        this.IdEscritorio = parcel.readInt();
        this.Nome = parcel.readString();
        this.Login = parcel.readString();
        this.Senha = parcel.readString();
    }   

    /**
     * Propriedades
     */
    public void setId(int id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public int getIdEscritorio() {
        return IdEscritorio;
    }

    public void setIdEscritorio(int idEscritorio) {
        IdEscritorio = idEscritorio;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return Nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        Nome = nome;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return Login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        Login = login;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return Senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        Senha = senha;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) 
    {
        out.writeInt(getId());
        out.writeString(getNome());
    }


    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Usuario> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Usuario>(){

        @Override   
        public Usuario createFromParcel(Parcel in){ 
                return new Usuario(in);
            }
        @Override
        public Usuario[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Usuario[size];
            }
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you make it like: `if(bundle != null)
{
        _usuarioAutenticado = bundle.getParcelable("usuarioAutenticado");

    Log.d(TAG, "IdEscritorio: " +  String.valueOf(_usuarioAutenticado.getIdEscritorio()));
}` and check the result again?

Comment: Same result in the log, the value remains changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your `Parcelable` class. In your `writeToParcel` class, you are writing only Id and Nome to the Parcel.

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) 
{
    out.writeInt(getId());
    out.writeString(getNome());
}
```

However, you are reading all 5 fields when creating the object in `Usuario(Parcel parcel)`.
For this to work correctly, change your `writeToParcel` method to:

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags)
{
    out.writeInt(getId());
    out.writeInt(getIdEscritorio());
    out.writeString(getNome());
    out.writeString(getLogin());
    out.writeString(getSenha());
}
```

Comment: Thanks you AesSedai101!